# How to pass string value to javascript alert

Tags: javascript

How do I pass string value to alert message for each empty field?

I have w, t, a, c and s. For example, if w is empty, it should give
the alert message "Mandatory field w must be filled out". And same
goes for others.

My javascript:

```
function addvalidation(){
        var w = document.forms["shop"]["w"].value;
        var t = document.forms["shop"]["t"].value;
        var a = document.forms["shop"]["a"].value;
        var c = document.forms["shop"]["c"].value;
        var s = document.forms["shop"]["s"].value;
        var c = document.forms["shop"]["c"].value;

        if (w == "" || t =="" || a == ""|| c == "" || s == "" || c == "") {
                alert("Mandatory fields must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: what if there are multiple fields empty

Comment: why can't you have `if` condition for each variables?

Comment: Better you have to keep if condition for all individual fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```js
function addvalidation() {
  var form = document.forms["workshop"];
  var ef = ['w', 't', 'a', 'c', 's'].filter(function(f) {
    return !form[f].value
  })

  if (ef.length) {
    alert("Mandatory fields " + ef.join() + " must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="workshop" onsubmit="return addvalidation()">
  <input name="w" />
  <input name="t" />
  <input name="a" />
  <input name="c" />
  <input name="s" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! But sorry, how do you make a field not mandatory but once entered must follow the email format. For example, email in this case is not compulsory and can be left empty, but when user type inside it must follow email format. http://jsfiddle.net/Qc2bd/577/

Comment: Need your most valuable help again. When i try to include the codes in this format. The filter doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/tn2fvh4p/68/

Comment: @Cloudburst that is a server side template.... what is the generated html.... in the browser select view source and check the generated html

Comment: @Cloudburst what is the server side technology used

Comment: @Cloudburst it can't be because there is no tag called `form:input`... are you using any html namespacing....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc2bd/691/ sorry how do i get this to work in this format? Its not mandatory and has format. but code must also be in this format. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can filter where `document.forms["shop"][e].value==""` and join them for displaying in alert

**Note/update:** You need to join keys not value

```
e = Object.keys(document.forms["shop"]).filter(function(e){
            return document.forms["shop"][e].value==""
        });


   errors = e.join(" ");
   alert(errors +" are mandatory");
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
        document.forms["shop"] =[] ;

        document.forms["shop"]["w"] = {};
        document.forms["shop"]["t"]={};
        document.forms["shop"]["a"] ={};
        document.forms["shop"]["c"]= {};

        
        document.forms["shop"]["w"].value = "";
        document.forms["shop"]["t"].value="abc";
        document.forms["shop"]["a"].value = "";
         document.forms["shop"]["c"].value="abcd";
        

    e = Object.keys(document.forms["shop"]).filter(function(e){
        return document.forms["shop"][e].value==""
    });
   
   
   errors = e.join(" ");
   alert(errors +" are mandatory");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for specific field alert,

```
function addvalidation() {
   var form = document.forms["workshop"];
   var field="";
   var ef = ['w', 't', 'a', 'c', 's'].filter(function(f) {
     if(form[f].value=="" && field==""){
        field=f; 
     }
   })

  if (field!="") {
    alert("Mandatory field " + field + " must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```